# how to update a variable in <script> tag from main?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In `index.ejs` I have a word cloud that is using `wordcloud2.js`.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <script>
                WordCloud(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
                    list: targetlist}); 
            </script>
```

In the main script(app.js) which is using express the following code generates targetlist and after that `index.ejs` will render again. I try to send the targetlist from the main script to front to generate word cloud.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(output.list)) {
               targetlist.push([`${key}`, value]);            
            }        
            response.render('index');
```

in my try I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: targetlist is not defined` error.

Comment: That cannot work.
Express is your server
Script Tag runs in browser on client side.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann so what is the solution?

Comment: I quickly checked what ejs is. Are you using it? Try <%= targetlist %> in html and pass the data to the render function.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasWiedemann, I've used it to send person info to HTML it works but in script tag is not working.